# Cyclic Thread start in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a for cylce that calls threads:

```
if(toModify[j]==1)
{
    getUpdate(methods_list[j],username, password);
}
```

`getUpdate` is a method which contains something like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
      // *** some operations***
  }
}).start();
```

Through for **cycle** I can run each `Thread` simultaneously.
But if I want that each `Thread` starts only after the previous has stopped, can I use the following trick?

```
if(toModify[j]==1)
{
  int returnValue =  getUpdate(methods_list[j],username, password);
}
```

and add at the end of `getUpdate` method this code line (outside of run method):

```
return 1;
```

Using the above code each thread can start only if the previus has stopped? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: You should really listen to what Tudor suggests. You don't need to create several threads in your situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RetrantLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

if(toModify[j]==1)        
  {   
      lock.lock();  // block until condition holds
 try {
   getUpdate(methods_list[j],username, password);         
 } finally {
   lock.unlock()
 }

}
```

Also you will need to call join() on thread that is started from getUpdate() method.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
        // *** some operations*** 
        } 
        }); 
    thread.start();
    thread.join();
```

Comment: What's the point of starting a threads if you immediately have to join it? That means the code can just execute on the parent thread.

Comment: @Tudor Yes I wanted to suggest him same refrained from it as it will not be answer.

Comment: @AmitD Refrained is just what I was looking for! thank you. I repeat that I don't want parallelism, but I have to use thread for lunch method for call web service, using Ksoap2 library.

Answer (score 2):

> But if I want that each Thread starts only after the previous has stopped, can I use the > following trick?

This means you have a strictly sequential execution and thus the entire code can be on the same thread. What's the point of starting multiple threads if there is no parallelism?

Comment: only because ksoap2 library methods can't run in main thread. 
I'm just looking for parallelism between main thread and ksoap methods.

Comment: @Joseph82: Then start a single parallel thread and run all your code there. No need for multiple chained threads, it's only a waste of time.